# Query Failed [Failed to execute main query] OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, elasticsearch, debian, out-of-memory

Hi i have data in elastic 80 M of data have 52 Go and i search in text with this query

```
$json_doc = '{
                 "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*' . $sujet . '*",
                        "lenient": true
                    }
                    },
     "size": 10000000,
     "from": 0,
     "fields": [
     "association_key","text"
                    ]
                }';
```

when I search a word that is in the base is looking less 20K I have my data but as his exceeds 20 K I have this error

```
[2015-11-14 20:03:04,663][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Pixx] [myindex3][2], node[x9gOi0WuQviXeE0eM6MsAg], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@3989d22b] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: [myindex3][2]: query[filtered(_all:*startup _all:maroc*)->cache(_type:tweecoms3)],from[0],size[10000000]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:297)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:56)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.HitQueue.<init>(HitQueue.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:275)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:37)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector$OutOfOrderTopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:135)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector$OutOfOrderTopScoreDocCollector.<init>(TopScoreDocCollector.java:133)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.TopScoreDocCollector.create(TopScoreDocCollector.java:262)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:490)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
    ... 8 more
[2015-11-14 20:03:11,764][DEBUG][action.search.type       ] [Pixx] [myindex3][0], node[x9gOi0WuQviXeE0eM6MsAg], [P], s[STARTED]: Failed to execute [org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest@3989d22b] lastShard [true]
org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhaseExecutionException: [myindex3][0]: query[filtered(_all:*startup _all:maroc*)->cache(_type:tweecoms3)],from[0],size[10000000]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:163)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.loadOrExecuteQueryPhase(SearchService.java:286)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:297)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:231)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$5.call(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:228)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23.run(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:559)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.lucene.util.FixedBitSet.<init>(FixedBitSet.java:187)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.docset.DocIdSets.toCacheable(DocIdSets.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.cache.filter.weighted.WeightedFilterCache$FilterCacheFilterWrapper.getDocIdSet(WeightedFilterCache.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.ApplyAcceptedDocsFilter.getDocIdSet(ApplyAcceptedDocsFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.FilteredQuery$1.bulkScorer(FilteredQuery.java:144)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.internal.ContextIndexSearcher.search(ContextIndexSearcher.java:191)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:491)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:448)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:281)
    at org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher.search(IndexSearcher.java:269)
    at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryPhase.execute(QueryPhase.java:157)
    ... 8 more
```

how i can resolve this problem i have dedicate server contains just a Intel Xeon W3520 c 4/8 t + 2.66 GHz RAM 32 GB ECC under Debian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: ES_HEAP_SIZE is no longer a documented option**

Elastic Search won't use all of that memory without being configured.

You need to configure and tune Elastic Search and Debian's memory settings.

You'll need to configure one of these:

- **/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options**: a file containing JVM options (file is at config/jvm.options (in a TAR or ZIP distro rather than a Debian package)
- **ES_JAVA_OPTS**: an environment variable with additional JVM settings including memory and GC tuning if needed (pretty much what's in jvm.options but in a single line separated by spaces)

Here's the relevant excerpt from Elastic's latest documentation as of February 2020:

> Here are examples of how to set the heap size via the jvm.options
>   file:
>
> ```
> -Xms2g ①
> -Xmx2g ②
> ```
>
> - ① Set the minimum heap size to 2g.
> - ② Set the maximum heap size to 2g.
>
> It is also possible to set the heap size via an environment variable.
>   This can be done by commenting out the Xms and Xmx settings in the
>   jvm.options file and setting these values via ES_JAVA_OPTS:
>
> ```
> ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g" ./bin/elasticsearch ①
> ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4000m -Xmx4000m" ./bin/elasticsearch ②
> ```
>
> - ① Set
>     the minimum and maximum heap size to 2 GB.
> - ② Set the minimum and maximum heap size to 4000 MB.

See more here:

- [Setting the heap size | Elasticsearch Reference [7.6] | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/heap-size.html)
- [Setting JVM options | Elasticsearch Reference [7.6] | Elastic](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/jvm-options.html)

Comment: Running against a Dockerized Elasticsearch 2.3.2 I found that setting `ES_HEAP_SIZE` alone didn't change my instance's heap size from the default. Adding `ES_JAVA_OPTS` did indeed change it, and seemed to ignore a lower setting for `ES_HEAP_SIZE`.

Comment: Good catch @eebbesen! I've updated as ES_HEAP_SIZE is no longer a documented option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have enough space for Java's heap.
Since it seems like you'd have more hardware wise you may try to increase it:
[Increase heap size in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)